# Trouble building boost 1.48

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2010

I am having trouble building boost 1.48 using my normal build command line, which in a Visual Studio x64 Win64 command prompt consists of:

```
bjam -j 8 --without-mpi --without-python --build-dir=vc100-bld-64-bit 
          --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc-10.0 architecture=x86 
          address-model=64 --stagedir=64-bit-vc100 debug-symbols=on 
          debug-store=database stage
```

The errors I get are `...failed compile` lines towards the bottom of the following output excerpt which complain about precompiled header inconsistencies:

```
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...found 9190 targets...
...updating 3251 targets...
common.mkdir 64-bit-vc100
common.mkdir 64-bit-vc100\lib
common.mkdir vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build
common.mkdir vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0
common.mkdir vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug
common.mkdir vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64
common.mkdir vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86
common.mkdir vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store-database
common.mkdir vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store-database\link-static
common.mkdir vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store-database\link-static\runtime-link-static
compile-c-c++-pch vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store-database\link-static\runtime-link-static\pch.pch
pch.pch.cpp
compile-c-c++ vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store-database\link-static\runtime-link-static\assoc_laguerre.obj
assoc_laguerre.cpp
libs\math\build\..\src\tr1\assoc_laguerre.cpp(6) : error C2858: command-line option 'program database name (/Fde:\dev\devel\libs\boost\boost_1_48_0\vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store
-database\link-static\runtime-link-static\libboost_math_tr1-vc100-sgd-1_48.pdb)' inconsistent with precompiled header, which used '/Fde:\dev\devel\libs\boost\boost_1_48_0\vc100.pdb'
libs\math\build\..\src\tr1\assoc_laguerre.cpp(6) : error C2859: e:\dev\devel\libs\boost\boost_1_48_0\vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store-database\link-static\runtime-link-static\libbo
ost_math_tr1-vc100-sgd-1_48.pdb is not the pdb file that was used when this precompiled header was created, recreate the precompiled header.

    call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 >nul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store-database\link-static\runtime-link-static\assoc_laguerre.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store-database\link-static\runtime-link-static\assoc_laguerre.obj...
compile-c-c++ vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store-database\link-static\runtime-link-static\assoc_legendre.obj
assoc_legendre.cpp
libs\math\build\..\src\tr1\assoc_legendre.cpp(6) : error C2858: command-line option 'program database name (/Fde:\dev\devel\libs\boost\boost_1_48_0\vc100-bld-64-bit\boost\bin.v2\libs\math\build\msvc-10.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\debug-store
-database\link-static\runtime-link-static\libboost_math_tr1-vc100-sgd-1_48.pdb)' inconsistent with precompiled header, which used '/Fde:\dev\devel\libs\boost\boost_1_48_0\vc100.pdb'
```

Is there something about my build command that makes the build fail?

**Update:** The problems occur due to the `debug-store=database` command line option to bjam. Is this option's syntax incorrect or did it change in 1.48?

**Update 2:** If you turn off precompiled headers by adding the `pch=off` option to the command, this problem goes away, but the build is probably slower, because precompiled headers are disabled.

Comment: I didn't think the pdb options worked ... I'm still on 1.45 though.

Comment: `-j` was quite buggy last time I tried it. Have you tried building without it?

Comment: Yes, I did try without the ```-j``` (parallel build) and got the same errors...

Comment: "pch=off" did it for me, thanks.